# How to make an instant search for div results?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I have results shows up inside a table, I designed it to show as grid by separating them by `td` for each.

I used a JS code to filter the results by a text written in textbox, but the only results shows is the labels!
I want each `td` shows as a result, complete with the contents (Image + Input + label).

Here's the JS code & example of a table same what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#table *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <input type="text" id="filter">
  <div name="table">
    <td>
      <label>Product1</label>
      <img src='/img/a.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="55">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Product2</label>
      <img src='/img/b.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="70">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Product3</label>
      <img src='/img/c.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="20">
    </td>
  </div>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you prefer vanilla JS solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase I think he has already tried with `toggle` but it is filtering all element instead of parent `td`. Which I have answered below.

Comment: @yogendarji yes, that was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest` [this link](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get parent `td` from your search and then `toggle` visibility.

below is logic to your solution.

`$(this).closest("td").toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();


    $("table label").filter(function() {

      $(this).closest("td").toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <input type="text" id="filter">
  <div name="table">
    <td>
      <label>Product1</label>
      <img src='/img/a.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="55">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Product2</label>
      <img src='/img/b.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="70">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Product3</label>
      <img src='/img/c.jpg'>
      <input type="text" value="20">
    </td>

  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine with a small correction from $("table label").filter(function() { TO $("table td").filter(function() {

Comment: @SamirJunaid BTW your `table` without `tr` is not a valid HTML as per the Spec but it won't give you error. FYI